# Retrieve the javascript value of a loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages, page 1 and page 2. 
Page 1 is loaded into page 2 using the jQuery load() function.
Page 1 contains a javascript value `js_value` which is created dynamically
in Page 1 after Page 1 is loaded into Page 2. 
I need to retrieve `js_value` in page 2.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: would help if you show the code that you say dynamically creates the value and your `load` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It should be loaded already**

When calling [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

Comment: Thanks, I have assigned js_value created in Page1 to the value of a hidden input type in Page2 and retrieved js_value using document.getElementById('id_of_hidden_value').value. This did the trick